# UIView.animateWithDuration in Swift - iOS7 issue

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, uiviewanimation

I am trying clear the data in a UITableView with some quick animation, I am using the below code, which works fine in iOS8.

However when I run it on iOS7 it only runs the **block after completion** , but not the first animation code *(fade out)*, so the animation looks very bad, the tableview disappears suddenly and returns back with animation.

any idea what is wrong here? what is the problem with it in iOS7?

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration (0.5,  animations: {

        self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2, 0.2)
        self.tableView.alpha = 0

        }, completion: { (value: Bool) in

            UIView.animateWithDuration (0.5,  animations: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
                self.tableView.alpha = 1
                println ("animation done")
            })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing UIView.animateWithDuration (0.5,  animations: { block inside completion block and check

Comment: I tried that already. actually that was my initial code. I added it later to see if it will make any difference.